# Soft-deleted item in Azure Mobile Apps not deleted in device

Tags: android, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Apps for Android. I am working on the local sync tables.

**Device A:** I insert item X. Call push() and pull().

**Server:** Item X is inserted.

**Device B:** Call push() and pull(). Item X is inserted locally.

**Device A:** I delete() item X.

**Server:** Item X is soft-deleted.

**Device B:** First I update() item X. Then I call push() and pull(). I am not getting any exception.

**Server:** Item X is updated and remains soft-deleted.

**Device A:** I call push() and pull(). Item X does not exist locally.

**Device B:** I call push() and pull(). Item X still exists locally.

How will **Device B** know that the item X is deleted? Push() and pull() doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `pull()` syntax from

```
mMyTable.pull(null, "myitem").get();
```

to:

```
mMyTable.pull(null).get();
```

With the first, the soft-deletes are not reflected on the client.